# How to populate rows from MySQL to dropdown menu using RedbeanPHP

Tags: php, redbean

please help me to populate rows from MySQL to dropdown menu.

```
$result = R::getCol("SELECT name FROM language");
```

I see all beans, but how can I put this beans into dropdown menu and can send multiple values to MySQL?

```
<select name="languages">
?????
</select>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That returns an array of values, so a simple foreach should process that nicely

> See [The RedBeansPHP Manual](https://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/queries)

```
$names = R::getCol("SELECT name FROM language");

echo '<select name="languages">';

foreach( $names as $name ) {
    echo "<option value='$name'>$name</option>";
}

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: I dont know, I just found RedBeans, looked at the manual to answer the above question.